# Xamarin iOS Linker causing AutoMapper issues

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, automapper, xamarin-linker

I am working on a Xamarin project that is using AutoMapper. When linking is set to "Link Framework SDKs Only" I get the following error when initializing the maps

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
> method

The exception is not much to go on and neither is the callstack

> AutoMapper.Mappers.ConvertMapper.MapExpression
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.ObjectMapperExpression
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.MapExpression
> AutoMapper.Mappers.NullableSourceMapper.MapExpression
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.ObjectMapperExpression
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.MapExpression
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.MapExpression
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreatePropertyMapFunc
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreatePropertyMapFunc
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.TryPropertyMap
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateAssignmentFunc
> AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateMapperLambda
> AutoMapper.TypeMap.Seal    AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Seal
> AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor
> AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor   AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize

The initial reading of that suggests that the Linker is simply removing some properties or indeed methods from some class we are using.

However, after commenting out most of the mappings and then reintroducing them one at a time I find that this class is currently causing the error.

```
[Preserve]
internal class ItemBase : CareRecordItemBase
{
      [Preserve]
      public string Topic { get; set; }
    
      [Preserve]
      public string InPractice { get; set; }
    
      [Preserve]
      public string PrivateVal { get; set; }
}
```

If I comment out the `InPractice` property the exception does not get thrown. This makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain why this might be a problem?

Are there better ways of diagnosing these issues?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comment from AutoMapper author Lucian Bargaoanu. I needed to include an xml file that adds configuration to the Linking process.

Lucian refers to this Automapper Issue, https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2272

Also see

[Custom Linker configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker)

Answer (score 7):

Based on Pat's Answer:

1. Add an XML file `LinkDescription.xml`, you can name it anything you want.
2. Add this code:

```xml
<linker> 
    <assembly fullname="mscorlib">
        <type fullname="System.Convert" preserve="All" />
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

3. Set the file's build action to `LinkDescription`

Comment: To others: I found mscorlib is the key, no Automapper special handling specifically. This answer works but I also found --linkskip=mscorlib works.